# Installing Opera on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 removes Apt

Tags: gnome, 17.04, opera

I am unable to install Opera (stable, beta and developer) on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. It says the installation of Opera requires the removal of 5 packages, apt and apt-transport being two of them.

Any ideas how to install Opera without breaking apt?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you try to install it (exact commands, download links or whatever you use)?

Comment: I downloaded the .deb files from opera.com/download and used gdebi to attempt to install.

When that didn't work, I executed sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_i386.deb

This is the result:

electing previously unselected package opera-stable:i386.
dpkg: regarding opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_i386.deb containing opera-stable:i386, pre-dependency problem:
 opera-stable:i386 pre-depends on apt-transport-https

dpkg: error processing archive opera-stable_44.0.2510.1218_i386.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing opera-stable:i386

Comment: First, you should always [edit] your question to add new information, especially for command outputs, as comments are length limited and do not preserve any formatting. Second, that output there said nothing about removing apt or anything, but that the dependency `apt-transport-https` is missing and needs to be installed first.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed same issue with my opera package. It demanded `apt-transport-https` even thought i have it installed in my system.
The problem is that the system was 64bit but package I downloaded was 32bit. I just needed to download and install right version.
Go to your download history in the browser and copy Opera url. It should be something like this:

```
https://download3.operacdn.com/pub/opera/desktop/45.0.2552.812/linux/opera-stable_45.0.2552.812_i386.deb
```

Change i386 part to amd64 and download it with wget. It should be like this.

```
wget https://download3.operacdn.com/pub/opera/desktop/45.0.2552.812/linux/opera-stable_45.0.2552.812_amd64.deb
```

When install it as usual with dpkg.

```
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_45.0.2552.812_amd64.deb
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: the `dpkg` command will need to be prefixed with `sudo` to work, though please note it may still need packages or remove packages so it may be safer to use something to install (like `sudo gdebi ...`. Which URL did you get the download link from?

Comment: @Wilf
I fixed missing prefix.
Opera is from official site.
https://www.opera.com/computer/linux
I've got 32bit version package because I downloaded from browser with switched useragent (32bit).